# I cleared all browsing data in Chrome, but right clicking on the tab in the toolbar shows past websites

Tags: google-chrome, security, privacy

I think this is a big bug, if I delete ALL browser data in chrome (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> and make sure everything is selected and the dropdown is everything), it deletes everything.

BUT, if I go to the Chrome tab in my toolbar in Windows 7, and right click, it shows websites I have recently visited and most visited etc.

This is really BAD!

Comment: If I'm correct, what you mean by toolbar is [the superbar](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Windows-7-User-Interface-The-Superbar-Enhanced-Taskbar-97143.shtml) and the list of visited websites you see is a [jump list](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/jump-lists). If you search for "clear jump list", you may overcome this bug.

Answer (score 1):

It probably cached the list in RAM and didn't remove that. Restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> ,It just deletes the history not the bookmarks. The links which are shown when type after wards are bookmark. 
Go to Bookmark Manager and delete all the bookmarks.